# How can I remove same word from the list?

Tags: python, string, list

I want to delete the same word `score`  from the all elements in list:

```
scorelist = ['100score', '200score', '300score'] 

scorelist = ['100', '200', '300']
```

Comment: What language do you use ?

Comment: python programming

Answer (score 1):

According to your comments, you're using Python. [How about](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23669051/7431860) `.replace()`?

```py
scorelist = ['100score', '200score', '300score']
newlist = []
for score in scorelist:
  newlist.append(score.replace('score',''))

print(newlist)
```

[Try it here!](https://repl.it/repls/WornOpaqueAdware)

In python, strings are immutable - that means they can't be changed. Just doing `score.replace('score', '')` isn't enough - this function returns a string that we can then capture and use.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

In PHP

```
function test_alter(&$item1, $key, $prefix)
{

    //  replace string
    $item1= str_replace($prefix, "", $item1);

}

array_walk($scorelist, 'test_alter', 'score');
```