# python remove all text between first and second comma in string

Tags: python

I have a string like this

```
gas,buck,12345,10fifty
```

how can I end up with this string?

```
gas,,12345,10fifty
```

Comment: You need to clarify your intent. Do you want to know how to remove the second element of a comma-separated list? Remove all occurrences of "buck"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option might be using list comprehension with `split` and `join`, although it might be inefficient:

```py
s = "gas,buck,12345,10fifty"

output = ",".join("" if i == 1 else x for i, x in enumerate(s.split(",")))
print(output) # gas,,12345,10fifty
```

Alternatively, in this *specific* case, you can use `re`:

```py
output = re.sub(',.*?,', ',,', s, count=1)
print(output) # gas,,12345,10fifty
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`str.find`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.find):

```
>>> s = 'gas,buck,12345,10fifty'
>>> first_comma_idx = s.find(',')
>>> second_comma_idx = s.find(',', first_comma_idx)
>>> s = s[:first_comma_idx+1] + s[second_comma_idx:]
>>> s
'gas,,buck,12345,10fifty'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regex with `re.sub` and a maximum substitution of 1:

```
import re
s = 'gas,buck,12345,10fifty'
re.sub(',.*?,', ',,', s, count=1)
```

Output: `'gas,,12345,10fifty'`

###### better example

```
import re
s = 'a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h'
re.sub(',.*?,', ',,', s, count=1)
# 'a,,c,d,e,f,g,h'
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try to replace your string like this:

```
your_string = "gas,buck,12345,10fifty"
your_string = your_string.replace("buck", "")
print(your_string)
```

output:

```
gas,, 12345, 10fifty
```

Comment: What if the string in the second element is unknown? Presumably the solution must be dynamic.

Comment: oh, ok. I guess you can use `re`, but I think they already have answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23669024/how-to-strip-a-specific-word-from-a-string)