# Weird python behavior when stripping from a string

Tags: python

What is causing this strange behavior???

```
In [41]: s = "Mr Magoo Myyopia"
In [42]: t = s.strip("Mr Magoo")
In [43]: t
Out[43]: 'yyopi'
```

but if I change up the contents of the string...

```
In [44]: s = "hello world again"
In [45]: t = s.strip("hello world")
In [46]: t
Out[46]: 'again'
```

Comment: `removeprefix` is method you need (py3.9+).

Comment: A simple removal of words, phrases or exact character sequences can be achieved using _replace_ search-string by empty-string like `replace('Mr Magoo', '')`, see [how-to-strip-a-specific-word-from-a-string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23669024/how-to-strip-a-specific-word-from-a-string)

Answer (score 2):

The [docstring](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) explains it pretty clearly:

> Return a copy of the string with leading and trailing whitespace removed.
> **If chars is given and not None, remove characters in chars instead.**

Any and all characters given to `strip()` are removed from the string if they are leading or trailing. `'Mr Magoo'` contains an `'a'`, which is also present in the `'Myyopia'` part - hence it also got stripped.

`'hello world'` has no characters which are also present in `'again'`, hence it is not stripped.

`strip()` works with characters, not substrings.

Comment: "Any and all characters given to `strip()` are removed from the string." Clearly not, as `'yyopi'` still contains an `o`. Why: "The outermost leading and trailing chars argument values are stripped from the string. Characters are removed from the leading end until reaching a string character that is not contained in the set of characters in chars." I.e. leading strip is stopping at `y` because the char is not in `'Mr Magoo'`, and trailing strip is stopping at `i` for the same reason.

Comment: the outermost values, tysm

Answer (score 0):

`strip` replaces the outermost characters, that are supplied as a string. i failed to recognize the "outermost" aspect. thanks everyone.